# How do you make an align environment use letters instead of numbers?

Tags: align

For the amsmath package, `begin{align}...\end{align}` will automatically *number* each line. But, what if you want it to letter each line instead? How do you make it use letters instead?

Comment: If you want to letter each line _globally_ in your document, follow @Partha's answer. However, in case you want to have some of your lines lettered and the others not, you can use `\tag{something}` after those lines, and they will be lettered `(something)`.

Comment: Suppose you have an `equation`: should it have a number or a letter? What if you have more than 26 “lettered” equations?

Comment: @egreg Then it uses combos like AA, AB, AC, etc.

Comment: @JouleV If there was a way to combine your answer and Partha's suggestions I think that would be the answer. What I am looking for is something that will automatically letter each line in a *specific* equation that can also be \noletter just as a normal align environment can be `\nonumber`ed.

Comment: Does your query apply just to `align` multi-equation environments, as the title and the body of your query would seem to imply, or to *all* numbered/lettered equations? If it's the former, how should non-`align` equations be numbered in your document? What about equations contained in `gather` and `multline` environments?

Comment: @user14554 I already posted an answer. See if it is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Equation numbers are stored and incremented every line in a counter named `\theequation` which can be used as follows

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \renewcommand\theequation{\Alph{equation}}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{align}
            e &= m\,c^2 \\
            a^2 + b^2 &= c^2 \\
            \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta &= 1
        \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

to get

[image: alph-eqno]

If you want small letters (`(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` ...) use

```
    \renewcommand\theequation{\alph{equation}}
```

instead.

Comment: If there are more than 26 numbered equations, one may load  `alphalph`and the re-definition `\renewcommand\theequation{\AlphAlph{equation}}` or `\renewcommand\theequation{\alphalph{equation}}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to letter your lines in some parts and number your lines in some other parts, you can define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{alignLetter}{
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \renewcommand\theequation{\Alph{equation}}
    \align
}{
    \endalign
}

\newenvironment{alignNumber}{
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \align
}{
    \endalign
}

\begin{document}
We have something like
\begin{alignNumber}
    1+1&=2\\
    (a+b)^2&=a^2+b^2+2ab
\end{alignNumber}

Besides, look at this
\begin{alignLetter}
    2+2&=4 \\
    \cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha&=1\\
    \tan\alpha\cot\alpha&=1
\end{alignLetter}

We also have
\begin{alignNumber}
    e^{i\pi}&=-1\\
    a^2+b^2&=c^2
\end{alignNumber}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Well, I know that my answer is not complete. I have to set `\setcounter{equation}{0}` to avoid (1)--(2)--(C)--(D)--(5)--... ;-) and that cause every environment to be counted from zero, which is bad. If you have found a way to improve this, i.e. to make something like (1)--(2)--(A)--(B)--(3)--(4)--(5)--(C)--(D)--..., please don't hesitate to edit my answer. Thank you in advance.